# scrpage2: unnumbered headings with \addsec get the wrong automarks

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[markuppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{part}

\begin{document}

% This works as expected
\part{Ancient writing and its influence}
\chapter{The origin of writing}
\section{Introduction}

\blindtext[15]

% But this doesn't
\addpart{Modern writing and its influence}
\addchap{The end of writing}
\addsec{Conclusion}

\blindtext[15]

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the headmarks in the unnumbered document half keep running like `[section]{chapter}` and I want them running like `[chapter]{part}`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt this is a _minimal_ example. Also, does this happen if you use `\section` etc instead of `\addsec` etc

Comment: @Seamus What do you mean?

Comment: I changed your example, which turned out to be quite interesting, to a truly minimal example. If you don't like my version, you can revert back to your version.

Comment: @lockstep I think you should have left in the `markuppercase` option, since the non-working marks are appearing not in uppercase while the working ones are...

Comment: @lockstep Also, change the names of the two sets of headings so we can see that the marks are actually referring to the _correct_ headings, just not referring to them correctly.

Comment: @Seamus: Good catch -- I re-added the `markuppercase` option.

Comment: I have edited the question title and the body to show that the right sections are being marked, just the wrong marks are being used.

Comment: @Seamus @lockstep Thank you for editing, I 'm sorry about the example. So... is it impossible with unnumbered marks (`/mark*` or `/addmark`)?

Comment: With an uptodate KOMA-Script version your code now works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `\part` issues a `\partmark` command to store the mark. `\partmark` stores more or less `\thepart parttitle`, that means it stores also the number. And so `\partmark` can't be used with `\addpart`. Same with the other `\add`-commands. So all of them use some hardcoded `\mark`-commands which are not suited for your example.

You will have to set the mark manually:

```
\addchap{The end of writing}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Modern writing and its influence}}{\MakeUppercase{The end of writing}}
\addsec{Conclusion}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Modern writing and its influence}}{\MakeUppercase{The end of writing}}
```

I also think it would be a good idea to show your example to the author of KOMA. It would be much better if one could separate the question *if* a sectioning command should set a left/right/both-mark from the question of the content of the mark.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. I found in Koma-Script doc the following solution (a little bit dingy).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,DIV=11, headings=small,numbers=enddot,pagesize,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,markuppercase]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{part}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small\rmfamily\upshape}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\large\rmfamily\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\partmarkformat}{}

\begin{document}
\part{Ancient writing and its influence}
\chapter{The origin of writing}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to declare the heading and footer and then choose the page style. From your example:

```
\usepackage[automark,markuppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\automark[chapter]{part}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}
```

Edit: Sorry and thanks Seamus for spoting the obvius mistake. And that wasn't obviously my code.

Comment: I don't think you tested this code did you? First, if you don't set the pagestyle to `scrheadings` the headings won't be set by `scrpage2`'s commands. Second, calling `\clearscrheadings` after setting all the headings just removes them all again...